# VirtualHost for django site on dedicated server with multiple web sites

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, rhel

So, i'm trying to run Django web site on my dedicated server which has multiple sites on itself and its folder structure looks like this:

```
home/user/www/
              site1/
              site2/
              site3/
              mydjangosite.com/
```

site1, site2 etc. are php/html web sites, and of course i need to keep them runing, so i'm wondering how should i configure my httpd.conf because these lines below are not working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot home/user/www/mydjangosite.com
    ServerName mydjangosite
    WSGIScriptAlias / home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing/wsgi.py
    <Directory "home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

I've modified my httpd.conf and instead of lines above (with VirtualHost *:80) i've added next:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/user/www/mydjangosite.com
<Directory /home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

and finally i've got Django succes page:

```
It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
```

But now i get that Django page for every domain that is on my server.

Comment: Define not working. Very hard to guess.

Comment: By 'not working' i mean that i don't get any response from server when i visit my web site location. In fact, i get only 'Default Web Site page', as i wrote to Somantra's reply (like there's not default index page (and in fact there isn't). Apache error log says: 'Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/****/www/mydjangosite.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/mydjangosite.com
    ServerName mydjangosite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing/wsgi.py
    <Directory "/home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Instead of:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot home/user/www/mydjangosite.com
    ServerName mydjangosite
    WSGIScriptAlias / home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing/wsgi.py
    <Directory "home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: @LjubisaLivac, I looked more closely and it looks like the DocumentRoot and WSGIScriptAlias nodes had a similar typo. Be sure to update those too.

Comment: still nothing.. i've added WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/www/mydjangosite.com/testing/wsgi.py (/ indicates the root url) but that didn't help either

Comment: What do you see a 404?

Comment: Do i maybe need to change something in my wsgi.py file? It's Django's 'Hello world' project, created with 'django-admin.py starproject testing', so i suppose that nothing should be modified...

Comment: So that looks like the default directive is superseding the django directive. Also I think you are on to something, the WSGIScriptAlias the way you have it is aliasing the root dir which is probably not right.

Comment: This is what apache log says for that specific domain: [Tue Mar 04 06:46:02 2014] [error] [client 95.180.***.***] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/****/www/mydjangosite.com/ I'm confused now...

Comment: The error indicates that the user that Apache runs as cannot access the directory you are pointing it at. This is usually because home directories are not readable to anyone but the owner of that home directory. Do not put stuff under a home directory of a user account, or otherwise change the permissions of the home directory and any other directories below it down to where your app files are so that the Apache user can access/read them.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Could be the problem that i want to deploy django on addon domain? Webuzo works by having one main domain and multiple addon domains. Because of that i can access to my web site in two ways: maindomain.com/mydjangosite.com and mydjangosite.com The first way gives me django 404 page, and the second way gives me Webuzo Default Website Page. I've checked and that directory has 755 permissions, so it should be regularly accessible.